# Adding two array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array 
one

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 30
            [b] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 30
            [b] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 30
            [b] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [a] => 5
            [b] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [b] => 15
            [a] => 0
        )

)
```

Second array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 207
            [b] => 225
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [b] => 35
            [a] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 35
            [b] => 90
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [a] => 80
            [b] => 140
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [a] => 40
            [b] => 35
        )
)
```

I want add these two arrays on same keys there are orders of keys are different on some positions [a] and [b]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have already used english

Comment: @user3024749 Please, give us an understandable question... your formulation is terribly confounding...

Comment: Please just see my full question

Comment: These are two arrays ,I want to add these arrays elements in php

Comment: @user3024749 We just can't understand a thing.

Comment: do you want to sum values of the same indexes ? 
Example : A[0][a]+ B[0][a] ?

Comment: @user3024749 please give an example of the output you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that these arrays have the same structure, this would hopefully give you a third array of the totals:

```
$array3 = Array();
reset($array1);
while (list($key) = each($array1)) {
    reset($array1[$key]);
    while (list($k,$v) = each($array1[$key])) {
        $array3[$key][$k] = $v + $array2[$key][$k];
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually seems to perform a bit better than mine.  Nice.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that both arrays are always the same length, and that the sub-arrays always only contain `a` and `b` indexes.

```
$result = array();

foreach($arrayOne as $key => $value)
{
    $result[] = array(
        "a" => $value["a"] + $arrayTwo[$key]["a"],
        "b" => $value["b"] + $arrayTwo[$key]["b"]
    );
}
```

[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/TCMnl)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a classroom assignment on for loops and arrays.

```
$array1 = array(....);
$array2 = array(....);
$finalArray = array();

$count = count($array1);
for (i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $totalArray[a] = $array1[i][a] + $array2[i][a];
    $totalArray[b] = $array1[i][b] + $array2[i][b];
    $finalArray[] = $totalArray;
}
```

Comment: I like @patrick-q answer better than my own, but alas, I only have 26 rep and can't comment on his answer.